# Are closed simple curves with this property necessarily circles?

Tags: geometry, area

> Let $\gamma:[0,1]\to \mathbb R^2 $ be a closed simple curve and $\Gamma$ be the region enclosed by $\gamma$. Let $O$ be the center of mass of $\Gamma$.
>
> Suppose that any line that goes through $O$ splits $\gamma$ into two regions with equal areas.
>
> Is $\gamma$ a circle ?

I have no experience in differential geometry or complex analysis. I'd say the answer is yes, but I'm looking for a rigorous proof.

Comment: What about a curve of constant width?

Comment: Many curves have this property, for instance ellpises, or squares, or regular polygons drawn from the $(2n)$-th roots of unity...

Comment: Please do not substantially change your question by an edit.  Ask a new question if you have a new question.

Comment: @StevenTaschuk So I should leave a dumb question in addition of creating a new one ?

Comment: Yes.  Questions and their answers are not just for you, even your own.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any convex centrally symmetric region has this property.

(I include the assumption of convexity only to ensure that there's no ambiguity about what counts as "split into two regions".)

Comment: In $\mathbb R^2$, a centrally symmetric region is the same thing as a region symmetric under rotation by $180^\circ$, isn't it?

Comment: @TonyK Quite right.  Fixed.