# Are closed simple curves with that property necessarily circles?

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, area, plane-curves

This is a more interesting follow-up to the question [Are closed simple curves with this property necessarily circles?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1295771/are-closed-simple-curves-with-this-property-necessarily-circles)

> Let $\gamma:[0,1]\to \mathbb R^2 $ be a closed simple $C^1$ convex curve and $\Gamma$ be the region enclosed by $\gamma$. Let $O$ be the center of mass of $\Gamma$.
>
> Suppose that any two perpendicular lines that go through $O$ split $\gamma$ into four regions with equal areas.
>
> Is $\gamma$ a circle ?

Again, I'd say the answer is yes, but I'm looking for a rigorous proof.

Comment: Consider any region with four-fold rotational symmetry, such as a square...

Comment: @Rahul A square does not have a $C^1$ boundary curve (it is only pointwise $C^1$). But if we round out the edges...

Comment: @Soke: Perhaps [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squircle)?

Comment: @Rahul is correct:  Any $C^n$ region with four-fold rotational symmetry satisfies your constraints---it need not be $C^1$ nor convex.

Comment: It's not true, you can have a ellipse with these properties.

Answer (score 2):

As commenters pointed out, any smooth curve with 4-fold symmetry   is a counterexample, such as $\gamma  = \{(x,y): x^4+y^4 = 1\}$.

Indeed, 4-fold symmetry means there is a point $C$ such that rotation by $90$ degrees about $C$ maps $\Gamma$ to itself. Consequently, such rotation maps the center of mass $O$ to itself, which implies $O=C$.

Since rotation by $90$ degrees about $O$ maps the union of   lines onto itself, the four regions into which they divide $\Gamma$ are mapped onto each other. Thus, they have equal area.